# Tronxy X5S losing steps during print

Tags: belt, tronxy-x5, corexy

This is my first printer, a core xy (Tronxy X5S) printer, and it is losing steps during diagonal movements. The curious thing its that fail is even, I've printed 2 calibration cubes and they are almost equals:

[image]

When it lose the step, you can ear a "toc" sound, as in this footage at 3s: https://youtu.be/aRJB--QBMC4 This is my realy first print, and I don't have much experience with 3d printing, thanks in advance for any information!

Comment: You turned down the print speed, but did you try to turn down the travel speed? If your printer is over extruding your infill will slightly stick up past the layer. When your print head travels across them it can skip steps. The reason that it happens at the same spot is that is where you have a long fast travel in the gcode that is sending it across your infill layers. Try calibrating the extrusion multiplier and or turning down the travel speed.

Comment: @PerplexedDipole you helped me a bit, i really changed all the speeds, but forgot to re-slice the object, at a low travel speed the problem don't occur, but this was not the root of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with my X5S when I first got it assembled. Because it's CoreXY, if one pulley slips, you'll skip steps in the diagonal. Check both set screws on your pulleys for the X and Y.

Comment: Perhaps my belts appear to be equally stretched they aren't, so I highly recommend a tensiometer (like this: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2230598) to be sure that you have both belts equally stretched.

Comment: This was the main problem, but also a lot of misaligment (motor pulleys, idle pulleys and belt position) was helping the problem to occur.